# $.ajax is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have recently started to learn Javascript and I am working on a small project. I am having an error stating "$.ajax is not a function". `endpoint`, `token`, and `body` are defined variables.

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: endpoint + token,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(body),
    success: function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

Anyone see a problem with what I have?

Comment: Is jquery actually available to you? Where did you 'import' it in the project?

Comment: have you added jquery file?

Comment: There are tons of JQuery tutorials out there :)

Comment: If you just mention `require` without actually importing it, your project don't know what is is jQuery. try adding this in the top of the actual page: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: you can even use `data: body,` if its an object, no need to stringify.

Comment: I npm installed it into my node_modules directory. I also have it saved to my package.json, so I don't think that it can't find it.

Comment: This question is tagged `node.js` so a `require()` statement should be enough to import any library.

Comment: I did `console.log($)` and it printed `[Function]`, so it does see it.

Comment: doesn't jquery need to be initialized with window or something? i don't think it just 'works' in node (ie server side)

Comment: http://quaintous.com/2015/07/31/jqery-node-mystery/ might help you. I honestly question why one would want to use jquery server side... What is a serverside ajax request good for? Does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @Christoph You can do server side ajax requests in universal/isomorphic apps for example, but no need for jquery of course

Answer (score -2):

2 Possible Reasons :

1. Check if jQuery has been added in your index.html (or whatever name you main html has) file.
2. If above does not relate to your problem, then you need to put a check i.e. is jQuery is available to you, something like below code :

   ```
   if(window.jQuery)
       { 
         ...do your stuff here
        }
         else{
               ... handle it according to your need here
              }
   ```
3. Also, don't forget to check if your document object is ready, if you are going to fetch a value from html inputs.

   ```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       console.log( "ready!" );
    });
   ```

Comment: All the mentioned solutions assume jQuery is loaded in the browser, but in the question node.js is used, so no browser is available per se.

Comment: No browser means no window and no document.

Comment: if jquery was not loaded, the error would most likely be a reference error about `$` not being defined.

Comment: That's exactly my answer is about i.e. to check if reference to ` $ `is present. -2 is not what above answer deserves.